# Access deployed library from nexus using maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a project structure as :

```
projects
|
|
|  |
|  +--bom
|  |  |
|  |  +--pom.xml [The POM of bom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
|  |
|  +--project1
|  |  |
|  |  +--pom.xml [The POM of project1:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
|  |
|  +--project2
|  |  |
|  |  +--pom.xml [The POM of project2:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
```

I have deployed a jar library of project 1 to nexus and trying to access it in project 2 pom as :

project 2:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>project2</artifactId>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

POM of project1:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<distributionManagement>

    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>deploy.snapshots</id>
        <url>
            <nexus server>
        </url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
<!-- Nexus Deployment -->
```

I can see the com.test.project1:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT under dependency tree of project2.

But, as I am trying to access a class(enumtypes.Activation.java) of project1 in project2 , I get error Error:(3,51) java: package com.test.enumtypes does not exist.

Not sure what could be the reason.

Comment: I did mvn clean install on project1 and also mvn clean install on project2 - but later once fails with mentioned error

Comment: Is project1 a regular Spring Boot application? If so, check out https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-an-additional-executable-jar

Comment: yes it is a regular Spring Boot application

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @[dunni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465223/dunni) there is a way to Use a Spring Boot Application as a Dependency.
Like a war file, a Spring Boot application is not intended to be used as a dependency. If your application contains classes that you want to share with other projects, the recommended approach is to move that code into a separate module. The separate module can then be depended upon by your application and other projects.

Comment: "If your application contains classes that you want to share with other projects, the recommended approach is to move that code into a separate module."